# Incorrect row delete with orderBy filter angularjs

Tags: html, css, angularjs, filter

I make table with AngularJS. I used `orderBy` filter. After it my delete function started to delete another row except I click to delete.

**Here is filter:**

```
<tr class = "table-row isActive-{{task.active}} rowNumber-{{$index + 1}}" ng-repeat = "task in tasks | filter:search:strict | orderBy: '-priority':true">
    <td>
        <span class="delete-link">
            <input type="button" data-ng-click="removeRow($index)"/>
        </span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

**and delete function:**

```
$scope.removeRow = function (productIndex) {
    $scope.tasks.splice(productIndex, 1);
    productIndex=0
};
```

what I missed?

Comment: You have to use the same order by in the `removeRow` function. The order by filter applied in the ng-repeat doesn't order the array itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$index` represents the index in the rendered table. However, you delete based on the index in the original array. `orderBy:` does not sort the original array but passes an ordered copy to `ng-repeat`.

**Solution:** You have two options:

1. Sort the original array and don't use `orderBy:`
2. Don't identify the item to delete by its index but rather by its id or the actual entry itself. Example:

   ```
   $scope.removeRow = function (task) {
       $scope.tasks.splice($scope.tasks.indexOf(task), 1);
   };
   ```